# Riley's, assemble!

Tags: riddle, word, wordplay, rhyme, affix-riddle

Time for a Riley - it's been ages since my last one...

> My infix is energy,
>   My prefix a curve.
>   My suffix full of honey,
>   And docs I preserve.

or

> My prefix a curve,
>   My infix entering through vein.
>   My suffix is earth,
>   And I am where records remain.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are an

> Archive

My infix is energy,

> **Chi** = variant spelling of qi, the circulating life force whose existence and properties are the basis of much Chinese philosophy and medicine.

My prefix a curve.

> **Arc** = a part of a curve, especially a part of the circumference of a circle.

My suffix full of honey,

> **Hive** as in, a beehive

And docs I preserve.

> **Archive** = a collection of historical documents or records providing information about a place, institution, or group of people.

My prefix a curve,

> **Arch** = a curved symmetrical structure.

My infix entering through vein.

> **IV** = [Intravenous therapy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intravenous_therapy)

My suffix is earth,

> **E** (suggested by SteveV in the comments) or could be [VE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bing_Maps_Platform) for *Virtual Earth*.

And I am where records remain.

> Archive

Comment: rot13( rnegu vf r)

Comment: nicely done, will award check later... this one's easy huh?